# Searching database with date

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, datetime

In my windows form, i have one text box where users enters the date in the format 16/02/2013 to search for all the entries on that particular date.
In database i have one column which stores date in this format.16/02/2013 02:47:36 AM.

Can somebody advise me with sql query to extract all the entries from database for that particular date and put it on dataset.

I am using this but it is not working.

```
public DataSet OrderByDate(string date)
{
    //  string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Amrit\\Desktop\\Database.accdb ;Persist Security Info=False;";
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

    try
    {
        oleConn.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT  Customer.[Title] + SPACE(2)  + Customer.[Customer's Name] as CustomerName, Customer.[Customer's Ebayname], Customer.[Email Address], Customer.[Phone Number], Customer.[Address 1] + SPACE(2)  +Customer.[Address 2] + SPACE(2)  + Customer.[City] + SPACE(2)  + Customer.[Post Code]+  SPACE(2)  + Customer.[Country] as Address, Customer.[Item Purchased], Customer.[Purchased Date], Customer.[Total Price] FROM Customer WHERE [Purchased Date] LIKE '" + "'" + date + "%'";
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oleConn);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Customer");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        oleConn.Close();
    }
    if (dataSet.Tables.Count <= 0)
        return null;
    else
        return dataSet;
}
```

In datbase the datetime is stored as Date/Time format.

Comment: Use bound parameters for your query instead of literals in the SQL statement.  That is not good practice. Also, a date/time is not a string, so "LIKE" does not really make sense here.  Should be a conditional operator ( <,> <=, >=, BETWEEN), etc.

Comment: i know that, i will change it once i can make this thing work..

Comment: You can't use `LIKE` with dates. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AmritSharma, which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Look into the BETWEEN operator for dates, and give it a range from midnight to the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

On the database side, if your datatype is date, you can simply do:

```
where yourdatefield = @dateIn
```

If it's a datetime, you do this:

```
where yourdatefield >= @dateIn
and yourdatefield < the day after @dateIn
```

Since you are using .net there are a couple of things you need to improve in your application code.  First, convert the date string to a DateTime object.  Second, convert all the user inputs to parameters.

Comment: do u have time to write query for me, I have no idea how can i make this thing work, stuck from yesterday

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not need to enclose the datetime in single quotes in the sql, I dont remember:

```
        DateTime start = DateTime.Parse("16/02/2013").Date;
        DateTime end = start.AddDays(1);
        string sql = "Select * From Customer WHere PurchasedDate >= {0} and PurchasedDate < {1}";
        sql = string.Format(sql, start, end);
```

Also, this is a quick and dirty method that I wrote up here. It should work, but you REALLY should paramaterize this query.

Answer (score 0):

Passing date values in this way does not work, because default formatted date and time value in .NET is not recognized by your SQL engine.

To pass any data to your query, it is best to always use parameters. Add a parameter to you command string:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE PurchaseDate = @pdate";

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pdate", date);
adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Customer");
```

`@pdate` in the command text is a parameter. Values for the parameter must be supplied before executing the command, as you see in the example.

You can also use simple string concatenation to fill in your values into your SQL statement, but that's only possible with simple integer or string values, and is generally not recommended because it is subject to SQL injection attack.