# SQL query to retrieve data using two dates

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, date

I am trying to retrieve data from database using two dates but visual studio throws syntax error.

Below is the method which fills the dataset using the sql query:

```
public DataSet OrderBetweenDates(string date1, string date2)
{


    //  string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Amrit\\Desktop\\Database.accdb ;Persist Security Info=False;";
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

    try
    {
        oleConn.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT Order.OrderNumber, (Customer.Title +SPACE(2)+ Customer.CustomerName) as [Customer Name], Customer.CustomerEbayname, Customer.EmailAddress, Customer.PhoneNumber, (Customer.Address1 + SPACE(2) + Customer.Address2 + SPACE(2)+ Customer.City + SPACE(2) + Customer.PostCode + SPACE(2) + Customer.Country) as Address,  Order.ItemPurchased, Order.PurchasedDate, Order.TotalPrice FROM Customer INNER JOIN [Order] ON Customer.[CustomerID] = Order.[CustomerID] WHERE [PurchasedDate] >= #date1# AND [PurchasedDate] <= #date2#";
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oleConn);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Customer");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An exception has been occured\n" + ex.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        oleConn.Close();
    }
    if (dataSet.Tables.Count <= 0)
        return null;
    else
        return dataSet;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you read [my answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009342/1174942)?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn, it works for single date and I think it should work for between dates as well. Please see the screenshot for error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way (**highly recommended**) is to use parameter. But if you don't want to follow best practises and always want to stay in trouble, try this:

```
string sql = @"SELECT [Order].OrderNumber,
(Customer.Title +SPACE(2)+ Customer.CustomerName) as [Customer Name],
Customer.CustomerEbayname, Customer.EmailAddress, Customer.PhoneNumber,
(Customer.Address1 + SPACE(2) + Customer.Address2 + SPACE(2)+ Customer.City
 + SPACE(2) + Customer.PostCode + SPACE(2) + Customer.Country) as Address,
[Order].ItemPurchased, Order.PurchasedDate, Order.TotalPrice
FROM Customer INNER JOIN [Order] ON Customer.[CustomerID] = Order.[CustomerID]
WHERE [PurchasedDate] >= #" + date1 + "# AND [PurchasedDate] <= #" + date2 + "#";
```

Did you notice the change? Your date parameters are contatenated to the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is as follows:

```
WHERE [PurchasedDate] >= #date1# AND [PurchasedDate] <= #date2#
```

Now `#date1#` and `#date2#` are not valid dates - you probably want to add parameters to your query for those. See the [answer MD.Unicorn gave you in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15009342/1174942)

Answer (score 0):

Besides your possible date format issue that has already been mentioned;

```
SELECT Order.OrderNumber, 
...
Order.ItemPurchased, 
Order.PurchasedDate, 
Order.TotalPrice 
...
```

`Order` is a keyword from `ORDER BY` and needs to - in all places - be enclosed in `[]`.

```
SELECT [Order].OrderNumber, 
...
```

Comment: Thank you for you feedback,, will do that,,